# Count frequency of each letter - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm utilizing JSBin to write a block of JS code to accept an input string, then return each letter included in the string (removing duplicate letters and other characters), then counting how many times each letter was utilized in the string.  I am trying to integrate regex for additional practice.

The code I've written is not removing duplicates, nor is it properly counting the frequency of each character.  Can somebody please tell me what I have done wrong?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input"></input>
  <button onclick="count()">Count letters</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="output">Result</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function count() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input").value.toString();
  var y = "";
  var z = [];

//Removal of white spaces and other characters.

  x = x.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,"");

//Elimination of duplicate letters.

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (/x.charAt(i)/i.test(y) === false) {
      y += x.charAt(i);
    }
  }

//Count how many of each letter exists within the input string.

  for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
      var freq = 0;
      if (y.charAt(i) == y.charAt(j)) {
        freq += 1;
      }
      z.push(freq);
    }
  }

//Write result to HTML document.

  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    document.write(y.charAt(i));
    document.write(", ");
    document.write(z[i]);
    document.write("<br>");
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please, please, please don't use single-letter variable names. `x`, `y`, and `z` are not descriptive, and even you won't be able to figure out what they mean a month from now. Also, why are you removing "duplicate" letters? What does that mean, exactly? What are you trying to remove?

Comment: Understood - I'm just writing quick code as practice, then deleting.  I'd use more descriptive variables for projects I intend to keep.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: To remove duplicates, essentially I'd like to take "hello" and convert to "helo" - then the output would count h 1, e 1, l 2, o 1 - since the initial string had two instances of the letter l, and one instance of each other letter.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz, He could have at leased changed `x`, `y`, and `z` to `e` (element), `s` (string), and `a` (array) respectively. It would have helped a bit more...

Comment: Can't you just use a hash.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking too complicated. Just iterate through normalized string, and count letters:

```
window.count = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value.toString();
  var result = {};

  input = input.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,"");
  var letters = input.split('');
  for(index in letters) {
    result[letters[index]] = result[letters[index]] +1 || 1;
  }
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0mbe0cy/)

Comment: Thanks Bogdan!  Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single replace function. This is an example.

```js
    function getFreq(str){
       var freq={};//an object to fill
       /*var tmp = result not required*/ str.toLowerCase()
              .replace(/[a-z]/ig, function(match /*that is [a-z]*/){
                  freq[match] = (freq[match] || 0) + 1;//fill object
                  return match;//do not change str
                  });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(freq));
      return freq;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="getFreq(this.value);" />
```